# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, testing, typeerror

I am fairly new to React-Native testing and am running into a TypeError that is saying navigation.addListener is undefined. I was attempting to log navigation to see the values but the code does not run to the point where it is shared. I completed one Snapshot test successfully but the other test is not running successfully for me. The screen being tested is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Logo from '../widgets/Logo';
import filter from '../../../assets/navigation/adjust-alt.png';
import settings from '../../../assets/navigation/settings.png';
import NavIcons from '../widgets/NavIcons';
import setStatusBarColor from '../utils/StatusBarColorFunctions';
import { COLORS } from '../../styles/COLORS';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [setColor] = setStatusBarColor();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener(
      'focus',
      () => {
        setColor(COLORS.white);
      },
    );
  },[])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Logo />
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          {
            [{ icon: filter, to: 'Filter' },
            { icon: settings, to: 'Settings'}].map(i => (
              <NavIcons
                key={i.to}
                source={i.icon}
                to={i.to}
                navigation={navigation} />
            ))
          }
        </View>
      </View>
      <Text>What are we looking to drink?</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity testID='Map.Button' onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Map')}}>
        <Text>Map</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})
export default HomeScreen;
```

The tests scripts so far are:

```
import '../../../matchMedia.mock';
import React from 'react';
import renderer, { act } from 'react-test-renderer';
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native'
import { RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(HomeScreen).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('renders default elements', () => {
    const { getAllByText } = render(<RecoilRoot><HomeScreen navigation={ { push: HomeScreen } }/></RecoilRoot>);
    console.log(navigation);
    expect(getAllByText('What are we drinking today?').length).toBe(1);
});
```

The Match Media Mock is:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
      matches: false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    })),
  });
```

If additional information is needed from me, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: You need to mock up a `navigation` prop object with an `addListener` function, or wrap the `HomeScreen` component in a wrapper component that provides it, in the unit tests.

Comment: @DrewReese is there a better/easier solution from the two?

Comment: Probably the first. It appears to be an object, just mock the bare minimum the component code accesses.

Comment: @DrewReese this resolved it -- thank you!